# count items in plist array

Tags: ios, plist

I am having difficult accessing the count of a chosen plist.  In the previous view controller, the user selects from one of several buttons, each one corresponding to a particular plist.  That plist is sent to the current vc as NSString * chosenPlist.  I have NSLogged to see that the documents directory and the plistpath seem to be correct, but the array that I want to count is still 0.
How can I count the number of items in the chosen plist?

```
NSString * chosenPlistPlus = [chosenPlist stringByAppendingString:@".plist"];

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSLog(@"The documentsdirectory is %@", documentsDirectory);

NSString *myPlistPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:chosenPlistPlus];
NSLog(@"MyPlistPath = %@", myPlistPath);



NSArray *arr = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile: myPlistPath];
//Trying to count the items in the plist, which is an array of dicts.
    int count = arr.count;

NSLog(@"Count is %i", count);
```

here is a log:

```
2013-11-16 21:13:07.037 GlobalHistoryRegents[70407:70b] The documentsdirectory is /Users/username/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.0.3/Applications/896EF347-A35E-40E2-9BE1-8CFAC5303347/Documents
2013-11-16 21:13:07.037 GlobalHistoryRegents[70407:70b] MyPlistPath = /Users/username/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.0.3/Applications/896EF347-A35E-40E2-9BE1-8CFAC5303347/Documents/methodologyQuestions.plist
2013-11-16 21:13:07.038 GlobalHistoryRegents[70407:70b] Count is 0
```

Comment: Can you post what some of these logs produce?

Answer (score 0):

try using,

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:myPlistPath];
NSArray *arr =dictionary[@"Root"];
```

Comment: That won't even compile.  The second line gets the error:

Called object type 'NSDictionary *' is not a function or function pointer

Comment: runs but still null.  Clearly it is either not finding the plist or the array is having some problem because it is stuck on null.  My guess is the first, but how would I know?

Comment: Ok I checked and the file doesn't exist.      BOOL fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:plistPath];
    NSLog(@"File exists? %hhd", fileExists);

Comment: can you please log the dictionary content. NSLog(@"Dict %@", dictionary);  If this is Null then path is wrong or plist is empty.Try checking using key Root to root

Comment: No.  It seems to think the file does not exist.  So how can I find the file or convince it otherwise?

Comment: how are you creating plist?. you can check file in finder.