# array from plist iOS

Tags: ios, null, nsarray, plist

I am trying to access an array that I am trying to have created from a plist.

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory =  [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *plistPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"methodologyQuestions.plist"];
    NSMutableArray *myArray = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:plistPath]mutableCopy];
    NSLog(@"%@", [myArray objectAtIndex:0]);
```

Here is a snapshot of my plist methodologyQuestions.plist
[image: snap]

The problem is that when I log the array it is null.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you verified that every other variable along the way is not NULL? Does `paths` return a valid array? Does `documentsDirector` return a valid path? etc.

Comment: Here is what happens when I NSLog both the paths and the documentsDirectory 
    2013-11-16 22:49:19.252 GlobalHistoryRegents[74153:70b] the      documentsdirectory is /Users/myname/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.0.3/Applications/896EF347-A35E-40E2-9BE1-8CFAC5303347/Documents
2013-11-16 22:49:19.252 GlobalHistoryRegents[74153:70b] the plistPath is /Users/myname/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.0.3/Applications/896EF347-A35E-40E2-9BE1-8CFAC5303347/Documents/methodologyQuestions.plist
2013-11-16 22:49:19.253 GlobalHistoryRegents[74153:70b] (null)

Comment: Sorry if that is unclear.  So it obviously found a path and the documentsDirectory, but how can I be sure it is actually finding methodologyQuestions.plist?

Comment: Yeah, that is odd. What happens if you don't make a mutable copy? Does just allocating and initing with the contents of the file work?

Comment: I found [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8758305/reading-plist-file) that might be of help. It seems like you might need to read it into a dictionary and pull the array out of that?

Comment: Yeah, taking out mutable copy doesn't make a difference.

Comment: Did you actually write the array into the Documents folder first? You can't read what hasn't been written. Perhaps you should be reading from the app bundle.

Comment: Right, I checked to see if file exists and it says no.  When you say read from the app bundle, what do you mean?

Comment: BTW - this appears to be a duplicate of your previous question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20026388/count-items-in-plist-array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are reading from the wrong path. If this is a file bundled with your app then it is not in the Documents folder, it is in the app's resource bundle.

The path is:

```
NSString *plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"methodologyQuestions" ofType:@"plist"];
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
NSArray * myArray =dictionary(@"Root");
```

Answer (score 0):

The plist was in the bundle, not in the documents directory.

```
NSString *file = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"methodologyQuestions" ofType:@"plist"];
    NSArray * arr = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:file];
    NSLog(@"%i", arr.count);
```

This should've been obvious if I knew what I was doing, but alas, hopefully this will help someone in the future who is trying to access their plists.